# Update App Engine model with dictionary

Tags: google-app-engine, dictionary, model, models, keyword-argument

You can **create** a new model in App Engine using a dictionary:

```
my_model = MyModel.get_or_insert(keyname, **kwargs)
```

Is there a way to **update** a model using a dictionary instead of doing the following?

```
my_model.firstprop = 'first'
my_model.secondprop = 'second'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no built in method to do this, but writing your own is straightforward:

```
def update_model(model, values):
  for k, v in values.iteritems():
    setattr(model, k, v)
```